# Windows Colour Management of common elements

Tags: windows, color-profiles, icc

It came to my attention recently.

I have a sub-par LCD and a profiling device (i1 Display). 
I have created a profile and have installed it (listed in Colour Management).

However, that did not affect the colour of Win32 elements at all. I am getting good colour reproduction in colour-managing editing programs (same appearance with very different LCD settings) but Windows is not changing colours of common elements. I even rebooted mh PC to be sure. There is a settings set in LCD which gives me more desirable response but I cannot use it because it results in terrible tint.

How do I make Windows to use ICC profile for common UI elements?